# .NET IQueryable to sql command text anonymouse type columns

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql, iqueryable

I try translane LinqToSql (EF 6.1) IQueryable query to SQL text (MS SQL Server) for use in util, that convert query result to JSON, that will latter bind to DataGrid. Don't ask me, please, why so happens. I found good example at [this link](http://www.codelocker.net/30298/get-sql-string-with-parameters-from-iqueryable-using-entity-framework/), every work fine, until I don't use anonymouse types. For example:

```
var query = from t1 in DbContext.Table1.Where(r => r.Column1 == "filter")
  select new 
  {
    t1.Column1,
    t1.Column2,
    Column4 = t1.Column2 == "v" ? t1.Column3 : "InitValue"
  }
```

this function create SQL query:

```
select t1.Column1 as [Column1]
  , t1.column2 as [Column2]
  , case when t1.column2 is null then t1.column3 else "InitValue" end as [C1]
from Table1 as t1 where t1.Column1 = 'v'
```

problem that this function translate *Column4* to *C1* and I cant't bind column C1 to DataGrid. How can I translate *Column4* to *Column4* instead *C1*.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the validity of your query (the original seems be selecting by Column1 matching "filter" and the sql is matching 'v' and == isn't valid sql), but to answer your question, all you need to do is replace

```
  as [C1]
```

with

```
 as [Column4]
```

I would have thought a more accurate sql translation would be

```
select 
   t1.Column1 as [Column1]
 , t1.column2 as [Column2]
 , case when t1.column2 = 'v' then t1.column3 else 'InitValue' end as [Column4]
from Table1 as t1 
where t1.Column1 = 'filter'
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I wrote this code for example, my code is very big for example. I understand your answer, but this translation is universal, this function will use for many LINQ query, and if there will more than one column (C1, C2, C3, ...) how can I know, what column in LINQ query match to columns in SQL query? I told about function, how can I modify it, for right LINQ query translation?

Answer (score 0):

the statements like

```
Column4 = t1.Column2 == "v" ? t1.Column3 : "InitValue"
```

will be always translated to CASE in SQL Server and named with capital 'C' for Case followed by number - position in SQL query, so you can just define DataBound Column to [C1] and it will be consistent as long as you will not move statement in your Linq to another place.